# QT C++. Update UI Elements from a different thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface, signals, slot

I am trying to find info/code about how to do that, but none of the examples on the net seem to work for me.

Can someone please help to just update lineEdit on a separate thread, so main GUI thread does not hang? If I can figure this out, I can thread other elements easily.

I have this test scenario:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class B : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

 signals:
  void update_signal(bool, int);

 public:
  void handleEvent();
};

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~MainWindow();

 public slots:
  void m(bool, int);

 private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

void B::handleEvent() {
  for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    emit update_signal(true, x);
  }
}

void MainWindow::m(bool x, int y) {
  QString tmpStr = "Rinning..." + QString::number(y);
  ui->lineEdit->setText(tmpStr);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  B* b = new B();
  QObject::connect(b, SIGNAL(update_signal(bool, int)), &w, SLOT(m(bool, int)),
                   Qt::QueuedConnection);

  b->handleEvent();
  return a.exec();
}
```

And this looks like this:

[image]

So yeah, the goal is to make this label update on another thread and not hang the main thread. Any suggestions, why my code is still executing on a main thread would be very much appreciated.

Regards.
Juris.

Comment: you speak of another thread, but so far I do not see it in your code. There are many questions in SO that respond to similar problems, have you tried searching for them?

Comment: I did, and I copied one of them and it tells that, when we create and connect signal+slot and emit the function, it should run concurrently. which is a Signal-slot mechanism. I am new to Qt, so any help would be much participated.

Comment: Have not you seen that they have been using QThread ?, could you point out the posts that you have researched?

Comment: You can get some idea of basic `QThread` usage from the [documentation example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood something. Qt does not create any extra threads for you automatically. Also, for basic Qt threading with signals and slots, you will need an entire QObject subclass, which you will move to this other thread, and which will emit signals from there. If this is not a threading exercise, you should probably use QTimer instead. Threads are for cases where you benefit (performance-wise) from multiple cores being in use simultaneously, or where code will be greatly simplified if you can let it just do calculation for long time without worrying about blocking the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your example work without any additional threads by invoking
     QCoreApplication::processEvents();
inside the loop of handleEvent(). This would yield (shortly) the control to the event-loop and allow to process events. In that case: the previously emitted signal.

For the medium and long run: use a QThread for the worker (logic) and the ui-thread shall only handle the ui-handling (input and painting).